# How can I use Angular JS $q service in this example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

In the below example I need to wait for the `drawFunc` method to finish before moving on to adding the opacity and eventually adding `foregroundPath` to the layer in Kinetic.

What would be a way to "wait" for the `foregroundPath` value before adding it to the layer using Angular JS $q service?

```
var foregroundPath = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    drawFunc: function(context){
        context._context.fillStyle = graphic.fill;
        try{
            fabricSVG.render(context);
        }
        catch (TypeError) {
            console.log('Caught TypeError!');
        }
    },
    fill: graphic.fill,
    name: 'graphicMainColor',
    scale: {x: imageScale, y: imageScale},
    rotation: graphic.rotation
});

foregroundPath.opacity(graphicOpactiy);

var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({name: layerName});
imageLayer.add(foregroundPath);
kineticStage.add(imageLayer);
```

**Update #2**

@anthony-c - Neither the `success` or `error` callback got called here.  Instead I used `$q.all()` since I'm also doing this same thing for a backgroundPath (I just didn't include it for brevity).  In this example, the `success` method always gets called first.  When I do `console.log()` I can tell the script executes *first* the `success` for all the promises and *then* it executes what's inside the `drawFunc`.  Shouldn't it be executing the `drawFunc` first before it runs the `success` method for all the promises?

```
var backgroundPathDeferred = $q.defer();
var foregroundPathDeferred = $q.defer();

// Graphic Shadow Color
var backgroundPath = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: x - 1,
    y: y - 1,
    drawFunc: function(context){
        context._context.fillStyle = shadowFill;
        try{
            fabricSVG.render(context);
        }
        catch (TypeError) {
            console.log('Caught TypeError!');
            backgroundPathDeferred.reject(TypeError);
        }
        backgroundPathDeferred.resolve();
    },
    fill: shadowFill,
    name: 'graphicShadowColor',
    scale: {x: imageScale, y: imageScale},
    rotation: graphic.rotation
});

// Graphic Main Color
var foregroundPath = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    drawFunc: function(context){
        context._context.fillStyle = graphic.fill;
        try{
            fabricSVG.render(context);
        }
        catch (TypeError) {
            console.log('Caught TypeError!');
            foregroundPathDeferred.reject(TypeError);
        }
        foregroundPathDeferred.resolve();
    },
    fill: graphic.fill,
    name: 'graphicMainColor',
    scale: {x: imageScale, y: imageScale},
    rotation: graphic.rotation
});

var promises = {
    'foreground': foregroundPathDeferred,
    'background': backgroundPathDeferred
};
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
    console.log('All promises resolved.', backgroundPath, foregroundPath);
    backgroundPath.opacity(shadowOpacity);
    foregroundPath.opacity(graphicOpactiy);

    var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({name: layerName});
    imageLayer.add(backgroundPath);
    imageLayer.add(foregroundPath);
    kineticStage.add(imageLayer);
    kineticStage.find('.background').setZIndex(9999);
    $('canvas').css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'});
}, function(error){
    console.log('Caught error!', error, foregroundPath, backgroundPath);
});
```

Comment: should be `var promises = {
    'foreground': foregroundPathDeferred.promise,
    'background': backgroundPathDeferred.promise
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with $q

```
var foregroundPathDeferred = $q.defer();
var foregroundPath = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    drawDeferred: foregroundPathDeferred,
    drawFunc: function(context){
        context._context.fillStyle = graphic.fill;
        try{
            fabricSVG.render(context);
            this.attrs.drawDeferred.resolve();
        }
        catch (error) {
            this.attrs.drawDeferred.reject(error);
        }

    },
    fill: graphic.fill,
    name: 'graphicMainColor',
    scale: {x: imageScale, y: imageScale},
    rotation: graphic.rotation
});
foregroundPathDeferred.promise.then(function(){
    foregroundPath.opacity(graphicOpactiy);
},function(error){
    console.log('Caught error!', error);
});
var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({name: layerName});
imageLayer.add(foregroundPath);
kineticStage.add(imageLayer);
```

Comment: Please see my "Update #2" on my question regarding your answer.

Comment: @Chad, did `foregroundPathDeferred.resolve();` get called?

Comment: You may need to call `$scope.$evalAsync();` after the promise is resolved/rejected, updated my answer.

Comment: I noticed that this line `kineticStage.add(imageLayer);` inside the `success` function was triggering the call to execute `drawFunc`.

Comment: I tried `$scope.$evalAsync();` and that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move that commands just before `drawFunc` exits:

```
var foregroundPath = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    drawFunc: function(context){
        context._context.fillStyle = graphic.fill;
        try{
            fabricSVG.render(context);
            foregroundPath.opacity(graphicOpactiy); // <-- move to here
            imageLayer.add(foregroundPath);  // <-- move to here
        }
        catch (TypeError) {
            console.log('Caught TypeError!');
        }
    },
    fill: graphic.fill,
    name: 'graphicMainColor',
    scale: {x: imageScale, y: imageScale},
    rotation: graphic.rotation
});

var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({name: layerName});
kineticStage.add(imageLayer);
```